# SQL LEFT JOIN with possible join condition duplicate match

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

Here is my query so far:

```
SELECT
b.cs_bidding_id, b.cs_bidding_user_id, 
floor(AVG(u.cs_rating)) AS cs_user_rating
FROM cs_biddings b LEFT JOIN
cs_user_ratings u ON u.cs_user_rated_id = b.cs_bidding_user_id
```

I would like to get the avg rating of the user's per bidding post.
However this does not work for multiple biddings because whenever the join condition is satisfied, it wont let me fetch other avg rating for other biddings that shares the same bidding_user_id

desired result:

[image]

Unsummarized Query:

```
SELECT
            b.cs_bidding_id, 
            b.cs_bidding_title, 
            b.cs_bidding_details, 
            b.cs_bidding_user_id, 
            b.cs_bidding_permalink, 
            b.cs_bidding_added, 
            b.cs_bidding_picture, 
            b.cs_bidding_status,
            b.cs_bidding_location,
            floor(AVG(u.cs_rating)) AS cs_owner_rating
            FROM cs_biddings b LEFT JOIN
            cs_user_ratings u ON u.cs_user_rated_id = b.cs_bidding_user_id
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Thank you for having a look at my question! I've added what my desired output should be

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is malformed.  It is an aggregation query (because of the `AVG()`) but the `SELECT` columns are inconsistent with the aggregation columns (well, there are none of those).

Fixing the `group by` might fix your problem:

```
SELECT b.cs_bidding_id, b.cs_bidding_user_id, 
       floor(AVG(u.cs_rating)) AS cs_user_rating
FROM cs_biddings b LEFT JOIN
     cs_user_ratings u
     ON u.cs_user_rated_id = b.cs_bidding_user_id
GROUP BY b.cs_bidding_id, b.cs_bidding_user_id;
```

I'm not sure if you want both columns in the `GROUP BY` (and the result set).  However, without sample data and desired results, it is unclear what you actually intend.

Comment: I would love to get the avg rating of the user foreach bidding. At first I tried fetching all posts then loop foreach post and fetch the avg inside the loop which is really bad.

Comment: `group by` really solved my problem. I'm sorry it took me so long to mark this answer as correct.